# How do I fix 'No module named 'blank_blank' in Jupyter?

Tags: python, importerror

When I run the following line in Jupyter everything works fine:

```
from source import load_image
```

But if I do the following, I get 'No module name 'project_code''.

```
from project_code.source import load_image
```

My source.py is contained in project_code folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: When Python is running your source, it doesn't know what your parent directory is called.  You can ADD that, using something like `sys.path.append( os.path.realpath( os.path.dirname( __file__)+'/..'))`, but if I were you I'd just stick with not using the module.

Comment: Do you know what a *current working directory* is? When you say "project_code folder", *which one*? Where on your hard drive do you expect Python to look for your code, and *why*?

Comment: My current directory is project_code folder. How do I change this directory?